# Flutter is not able to detect folder name with spaces in it

Tags: android, flutter, yaml

I'm trying to build a flutter application that read links that are stored in a txt file under a folder. I have more than 200 folders that are in a nested manner and each folder has a txt file in it. The purpose of the app is to read a link from the txt file and fetch the file from that online link. Every section of the app is working perfectly, except for a single one.

This is the code I'm using to read the txt :-

```
void getFileData() async {
  String text=await rootBundle.loadString("assets/links/3rd/EEE/Linear Algebra/1.txt");
  print(text);
  downloadPDF(text);
}
```

The problem is that if there's a whitespace in the folder's name I get an error saying 'can't load the asset'. On the other hand, if I pick a folder that doesn't have any spaces in between, everything works perfectly.

Here's my pubspec.yaml :-

```
name: it_repeats
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  flutter_pdfview:
  path_provider:
  http:
  flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer:
  liquid_progress_indicator: ^0.3.2
  dio: 




dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_icons:
  android:true
  ios:true
  image_path:"assets/icon.png"


flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/links/3rd/CSE/COA/1.txt
    - assets/links/3rd/EEE/Linear Algebra/1.txt
```

The folders are perfectly detected in the pubspec.yaml, and I don't receive any error while
running packages get.

What is the problem and how can I resolve it? I've been scratching my head over this thing since a couple of days and I can't seem to find anything that could resolve this.

Comment: `"assets/links/3rd/EEE/Linear Algebra/1.txt"`. Try `"\"assets/links/3rd/EEE/Linear Algebra/1.txt\""` instead.

Comment: If that does not help try to replace(" ", "%20").

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge I suggest you to remove white spaces in the folder name. As I guess it doesn't matter to particularly include white space instead use **_** for a better understanding of

Comment: Removing spaces from more than 200 folders would be quite a job!!!

Comment: You can write a script that does it for you.